# Cocos2d: Difference between ccp and CGPointMake?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d, many things require a.. point. Or position. I have used both ccp and CGPointMake methods, and both have worked just fine for me.

However, I've seen, in some tutorials, that people use one or both of them in all their examples. So I'm not sure if there's an actual difference (because if there wasn't a difference, I'd just use the quick method ccp).

Comment: the documentation says "Helper macro that creates a CGPoint".  it certainly doesn't _help_ more than `CGPointMake`, so the question(s) becomes: why is it there? does it facilitate cross platform porting?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope no difference except CGPointMake is harder to type:

```
#define     ccp(__X__, __Y__)   CGPointMake(__X__,__Y__)
```

Found here:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.3/_c_g_point_extension_8h_source.html